# Send JSON body with SIM900 board

Tags: serial, gsm, http

I'm trying to send JSON, but i'm not able to set `Content-Type` header.
Other commands are successful:

```
[23:49:41:856] AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"␍␊
[23:49:41:899] ␍␊
[23:49:41:899] OK␍␊
[23:49:52:327] AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"␍␊
[23:49:52:367] ␍␊
[23:49:52:367] OK␍␊
[23:49:59:585] AT+CSQ␍␊
[23:49:59:594] ␍␊
[23:49:59:610] +CSQ: 18,0␍␊
[23:49:59:610] ␍␊
[23:49:59:621] OK␍␊
[23:50:07:449] AT+SAPBR=1,1␍␊
[23:50:08:501] ␍␊
[23:50:08:512] OK␍␊
[23:50:13:900] AT+SAPBR=2,1␍␊
[23:50:13:928] ␍␊
[23:50:13:928] +SAPBR: 1,1,"127.0.0.1"␍␊
[23:50:13:955] ␍␊
[23:50:13:955] OK␍␊
[23:50:21:261] AT+HTTPINIT␍␊
[23:50:21:291] ␍␊
[23:50:21:291] OK␍␊
[23:50:40:284] AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1␍␊
[23:50:40:320] ␍␊
[23:50:40:320] OK␍␊
[23:50:47:652] AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"␍␊
[23:50:47:713] ␍␊
[23:50:47:713] OK␍␊
[23:50:54:359] AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"␍␊
[23:50:54:414] ␍␊
[23:50:54:414] +CME ERROR: operation not allowed␍␊
[23:51:06:576] AT+HTTPDATA=38,10000␍␊
[23:51:06:612] ␍␊
[23:51:06:612] DOWNLOAD␍␊
[23:51:12:034] ␍␊
[23:51:12:050] OK␍␊
[23:51:19:386] AT+HTTPACTION=1␍␊
[23:51:19:414] ␍␊
[23:51:19:414] OK␍␊
[23:51:27:747] ␍␊
[23:51:27:758] +HTTPACTION:1,500,290␍␊
[23:51:35:599] AT+HTTPREAD␍␊
[23:51:35:628] ␍␊
[23:51:35:628] +HTTPREAD:290␍␊
[23:51:35:635] <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">␊
[23:51:35:692] <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>␊
[23:51:35:735] <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>␊
[23:51:35:766] <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>␊
[23:51:35:935] ␍␊
[23:51:35:935] OK␍␊
```

*ip addresses aren't real.*

My server received invalid request (with JSON body, but without special header), and replied `500 Internal Server Error`.

Revision: 1137B08SIM900M64_ST_DTMF_JD_MMS

Comment: 127.0.0.1?! How do you expect to get there?

Comment: I wrote `ip addresses aren't real.`. I don't want to share my public ip.

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit. I'm viewing on my phone at the moment.

Comment: You need firmware version B10 to use the content Param. You have B08.

Comment: @Majenko, thank for your reply. At the moment I'm trying to upgrade to 1137B15SIM900M64_ST through pl-2303hx adapter, but my attempts are unsuccessful.

Comment: It's not something I have ever tried (I have never used a SIM900), so I can't help with that sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for **@Majenko**.
I solved problem by upgrade firmware to **1137B15SIM900M64_ST**.